# Why all tasks are using same cpu core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, multitasking

First of all I am new to multithreading or multitasking but working hard on it. I'm trying to search a SQL database two different ways: the first searches IDs below the midpoint, the second searches IDs above the midpoint. I want to run both searches at the same time; the program works, but when I check in Task Manager all searches are working on one core.

I can't figure out how to fix this. Here's my code; please can you help me?

```
 public int SearchForTweetSqlID(string TweetID, string TempQuery, int MidPoint)
    {
        int ResultSmallSearch = 0;
        int ResultBigSearch = 0;

        Parallel.Invoke(() => ResultSmallSearch = TaskSearchSqlTweetID(TweetID, TempQuery, MidPoint, true).Result,
               () => ResultBigSearch = TaskSearchSqlTweetID(TweetID, TempQuery, MidPoint, false).Result
            );

        int TweetSqlID = 0;
        if (ResultSmallSearch != 0)
        {
            TweetSqlID = ResultSmallSearch;

        }
        if (ResultBigSearch != 0)
        {
            TweetSqlID = ResultBigSearch;
        }

        return TweetSqlID;
    }




     public async Task<int> TaskSearchSqlTweetID(string TweetID, string Query, int Midpoint, bool way)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Tools.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

        if (way == true)
        {
            comm = new SqlCommand("select * from Tweets where @VsTweetID=TweetID and ID>@VsMidPoint", conn);

        }
        else
        {
            comm = new SqlCommand("select * from Tweets where @VsTweetID=TweetID  and ID<@VsMidPoint", conn);

        }
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VsTweetID", TweetID);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vsMidPoint", Midpoint);

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

        Tweets Gidecek = new Tweets();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Gidecek.ID = dr.GetInt32(0);

            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();

            int sonuc = await Task<int>.FromResult(Gidecek.ID);

            return sonuc;

        }
        else
        {
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
            int sonuc = await Task<int>.FromResult(0);

            return sonuc;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Doing `await Task<int>.FromResult` does nothing for you except make your program slower by adding overhead. If you want to be using async you need to do stuff like replacing all your `SqlReader` code with a call to [`ExecuteScalarAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223677.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain   `ExecuteScalarAsync` was really a life saver thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you expect two IO bound tasks to be on different CPUs? Can you explain your thought process here?

Comment: @EricLippert I thought about your comment and I think you are right.But I am new at multitaksing issue I will learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot specify core for thread from managed code. It is the very basic concept of managed code that all memory, threading and etc tasks are managed by VM and OS.

The second thing that you won't reach any optimization with SQL with the code I see, because SQL queries run at SQL-server, not in you code.

Comment: (1) Inability to force threads started by Parallel.Invoke does not explain why the threads aren't running in parallel. (2) The fact that work is done server-side for SQL queries does not mean multiple queries can't run faster in parallel.

Comment: Threads can run in parallel on the single core. It's really hard to make .net to run 2 simple tasks on different cores. Try to make threaded app that eg. computes prime numbers and run tens of threads. So you'll be able to see how threads distributed between cores.